# Query related models

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models (Survey and Question) which are related with each other. I want to query all the Questions related to a specific Survey:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_survey_set")
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return (self.name)

    def questions(self):
        if self.pk:
            return Question.objects.filter(survey=self.pk)
        else:
            return None

    def user_data(self):
        p = self.user
        return p.name


class Question(models.Model):
    TEXT = 'text'
    RADIO = 'radio'
    SELECT = 'select'
    SELECT_MULTIPLE = 'select-multiple'
    INTEGER = 'integer'

    QUESTION_TYPES = (
        (TEXT, 'text'),
        (RADIO, 'radio'),
        (SELECT, 'select'),
        (SELECT_MULTIPLE, 'Select Multiple'),
        (INTEGER, 'integer'),
    )


    text = models.TextField()
    required = models.BooleanField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=QUESTION_TYPES, default=TEXT)
    choices = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,
                               help_text='if the question type is "radio", "select" or "select multiple" provide a comma separated list for this question')
```

How can I use the def questions property of the Survey model?

I'm trying to do like this in the shell:

```
s = Survey.objects.filter(id=1)
s.questions()
```

But this doesn't work. How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you fetch the questions:

```
q = Survey.objects.get(id=1)
q.question_set.all()
```

[Here's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) the relevant docs section.

You can also set `related_name` to your FK field like:

```
survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, related_name='questions')
```

this makes accessing questions more meaningful:

```
q = Survey.objects.get(id=1)
q.questions.all()
```

Remember to use `get` instead of `filter` (`filter` returns list of objects instead of single object).

Finally by using what we've learned, you can now change your custom method like so:

```
def questions(self):
    if self.pk:
        return self.questions.all()
    else:
        return None
```